# Animate objects one after one by changing class names

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.box1').addClass('animated').delay(50).queue(function () {
        $('.box2').addClass('animated').delay(50).queue(function () {
            $('.box3').addClass('animated').delay(50).queue(function () {
                $('.box4').addClass('animated').delay(50).queue(function () {
                    $('.box5').addClass('animated').delay(50).queue(function () {
                        $('.box6').addClass('animated').delay(50).queue(function () {

                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

i need to know how to simplify this(like using `++i`). i need this animation on page load.

without type code for animation to all the classes(`.box1`, ...).

Comment: I wonder if it would be more efficient to manage the animation delays through CSS using the `animation-delay` property with various rules for the different boxes when they have the `animated` class (`.box1.animated`, `.box2.animated`, etc.) and then just apply `animated` to them all at once in your `ready` callback. It would be easier to change the order of delays this way, at least, though it would be harder to propagate changes to one delay. There may be ways of using CSS keyframes to simplify/enhance the process, but I don't have enough experience with animating via CSS to talk about that.

Answer (score 3):

You can give all of the "box"es the same class and try something like this:

```
(function () {
    var index = 0;

    function start() {
        $('.box:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('animated');
        ++index;
        setTimeout(start, 50);
    };
    start();
})();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/kQWgj/

Or something like this to cache all of the "box"es:

```
(function () {
    var index = 0;
    var boxes = $('.box');

    function start() {
        boxes.eq(index).addClass('animated');
        ++index;
        setTimeout(start, 50);
    };
    start();
})();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/6QseP/

Comment: umm... interpolated selectors don't look good. Why not store `$('.box')` somewhere and loop over that?

Comment: Not to mention I don't think `:eq` is a native pseudo-class. You don't want to force Sizzle to do the heavy lifting instead of the browser.

Comment: @JanDvorak I added that as an option

Comment: can you do it with different class  names

Comment: @user2607456 do what?

Comment: if each .box have different animations, (like moving different lengths.) how to animate all objects one after one.

Comment: Elements can have multiple class names. You can still have `box1`, `box2`, etc on each element, and it will still work the same as before.

Comment: @user2607456 happy to help :-D